# get scatter c=? Colormap and Normalize

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I created a scatter with variable c which give me color per value like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3]
y=[3,5,2]
c=[10,7,19]

scplot = plt.scatter(x,y,c=c)
```

now I want to get the color that will fir the number 9, how can I do it.
I know that I can get the camp using scplot.get_cmap(), but how would I get the normalization from the scatter (I also know that I can do it manually, but the question is can I extract it from the scplot)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about the color cycle?: https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colors-in-default-property-cycle

Comment: @sshashank124 thanks.. No I am looking on how to get the color for each number from the colormap that was created in the scatter for the values in c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:
`scplot.norm(x)` will give me the normalized value per number.

So to get the color for the number 9 I need to to

```
cma = scplot.get_cmap()
cma(scplot.norm(9))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Self sufficient. Perfect